Android ONNXRuntime Multi Thread multi models
I am trying to run two different models on android device and I successfully made two different sessions and run two models.
But the problem is that they are running in serialized manner which is inefficient. I want to run them in parallel using multi threading and match their time of inference.
How can I do that??
(I am new to android studio fyi)
Here is the sample code of how I built two models to run in serialized manned:
private suspend fun createOrtSession(): OrtSession? {
    val so = OrtSession.SessionOptions()
    so.use {
        return ortEnv?.createSession(readModel(), so)
    }
}
private suspend fun createOrtSession2(): OrtSession? {
    val so = OrtSession.SessionOptions()
    so.use {
        return ortEnv?.createSession(readModel2(), so)
    }
}

private fun setORTAnalyzer() {
    scope.launch {
        imageAnalysis2?.clearAnalyzer()
        imageAnalysis2?.setAnalyzer(
            backgroundExecutor,
            ORTAnalyzer(createOrtSession(), createOrtSession2(), ::updateUI)
        )
    }
}

    val env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment()

    env.use {
        val tensor = OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, imgData, shape)
        val tensor2 = OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, imgData2, shape2)

        val startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        tensor2.use {
            val timeStart2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val output2 = ortSession2?.run(Collections.singletonMap(inputName2, tensor2))

            result2.log.add("Depth Model 결과 : " + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart2))
            output2.use {

                val depthArray = output2?.get(0)?.value as Array<Array<FloatArray>>

            }
        }

        tensor.use {

            val timeStart3 = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val output = ortSession?.run(Collections.singletonMap(inputName, tensor))

